# How to add query string to htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I have below code in the htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([en|ar]{2})/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Its working fine if the url is `http://test.localhost/en/home/`

But its not working if the url is `http://test.localhost/en/category/1/`

I tried the below code but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^([en|ar]{2})/(.*)/(.*)$ $3?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: try with `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+).php /page.php?search=$1&sort=$2 [NC]`

Comment: I can only guess what you want to achieve - rewriting `http://test.localhost/en/category/1/` to `http://test.localhost/category/1?lang=en&...` ?

Comment: Please do confirm from which file you want to serve this link? eg: `index.php` and what all are the parameters you want to pass as a query string to it? eg: `category` OR `lang` etc?

Comment: This is bilingual website. I am adding the en or ar followed by the domain. 
For ex. Home page -> test.localhost/en/home/
Category page -> test.localhost/en/category/1
Product Page -> test.localhost/en/product/1

Currently its working if the url is test.localhost/en/home or test.localhost/en/account/

and its not working if the url is test.localhost/en/category/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `([en|ar]{2})` is not correct as characters are not grouped inside `[...]`. In other words it can match `ee`, `er`, `||`, `aa` also which is not what you want.

Change your rule to this:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(en|ar)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And make sure there are no other conflicting rewrite rules. In case this doesn't work I suggest you provide your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: @user2468312: Did this work out?